# Solve equations: $x+y+z+w=30$; $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

> I have been trying to find the solutions to the joint equations below,
>
> $$x+y+z+w=30$$
>   $$x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$$
>
> where $x$, $y$, $z$ and $z$ are distinctive natural numbers.

I have not worked with integer equations that much and do not seem to have equipped myself with a systematic approach as I do real equations. So, with certain reasoning and some reluctant trial-and-errors, I was able to come up with one set of solutions, only after about a good hour spent.

I am not sure how to tell if there are other solutions and aware that my method is inefficient to find them. I would like to see if there is a clean algebraic way to find all the solutions.

Comment: Look at the three integer solution [*WA*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Bx%2By%2Bz%2Bw%3D30%2C+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3Dz%5E2%2Bw%5E2%7D%2C+over+integers)

Comment: You have $x=10, y=5, z=10, w=5$ right?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify they are distinctive

Comment: You said you had one set of solutions. What solution is it?

Comment: (3,7,9,11) is what I have

Comment: @Quanto But $9+49\ne 81+121.$

Comment: By the way, what problem led to this? What were you trying to do?

Comment: @Allawonder:  $9+121=49+81$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I see. I'd taken his tuple as ordered.

Comment: Another alternative is to brute force it. Since $30$ is small, it may be possible (by computer, of course) to list all the $4$-partitions of $30$ into distinct parts. Of course, in this case one would lose the negative solutions, but that's one step ahead. I don't know the partition numbers offhand, so I can't say presently how may checks one would have to make.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution of $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$ is given by the identity
$$(ab+cd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(ab-cd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary integers.
It follows that we have to take  $a,b,c,d$ such that
$$2a(b+d)=30\iff a(b+d)=15$$ For example $(a,b,d)=(3,1,4)$ gives the following  parameterization of solutions with the parameter $t$
$$\begin{cases}x=3+4t\\y=12-t\\z=3-4t\\w=12+t\end{cases}$$

Comment: Nice approach -- introducing four parameters. However, can we be sure that all solutions of the quadratic are given by the quadratic binomials? You need not explain here -- you may refer to somewhere I can find it. Thanks.

Comment: @Allawonder: The OP says "natural numbers". You can have all the possible ones this way.

Comment: Ah, I think that's after an edit. In any case that was not my point. You have given an infinite set of solutions to the quadratic; my question is if it can be shown that *all* solutions of the quadratic are of the given forms; that is, can you justify your claim that that is the general solution? Surely you recognise that these are two different things?

Comment: In general when la parameterization comes from an identity it gives all the solutions. If you take a solution the equation $x=ab+cd$ have infinitely many solutions and so is for $z=ab-cd$ so you can deduce for the solution $(x,y,z,w)$ suitable values. The same goes for, for example, for the Pythagorean triples.

Comment: I don't think that claim is true. That you can produce infinitely many solutions doesn't imply you've produced all solutions. As for the solution to the Pythagorean equation, that has been shown to be the general solution. I'm not sure if I remember the proper reference, but I think I read a geometric proof in Shafarevich's great book on algebra. So, in general, one has to make sure that the family one describes gives *all* solutions.

Comment: You are free to think what you think. I suggest you take a solution $(x, y, z, w)$ and prove that the corresponding system with $(a, b, c, d)$ has no solution. In this way you will have shown that in truth all the solutions by that parameterization are not represented. Shafarevich is a great Russian mathematician but he is publicly declared anti-Jewish which is not exactly sympathetic. Regards.

Comment: LOL, what are you talking about being anti-Jewish or whatever. This is a simple mathematical question -- you have *not shown* that your solution is the general solution. Your claim is not justified. That's what this is about, not about what Shafarevich believes. This is funny!

Comment: For me it is not at all funny to be one-dimensional or Marcusian.

Comment: I don't care what you think about Shafarevich -- neither for, that matter, does anyone vis-à-vis the real question here, namely whether you have indeed provided all solutions.

Comment: Read "Diophantine Equations" of (nothing less than!) L.J. Mordell. Academic Press, London and New York. (1969). Page 15. There you will see how easy Mordell shows in four lines that this parameterization gives all the solutions (which the OP did not ask for). I admire Shafarevich.

Comment: This is quite interesting. First, I'll note that if you'd given this straightaway (or admitted to your ignorance) a lot of unnecessary discussion would have been saved. As for OP's question, it's quite disingenuous of you to think that if someone asks for the solution of an equation, they are asking for anything less than *all* solutions, provided they do not specifically ban some. Here, OP has only ruled out solutions involving repeated coordinates; thus, if you'd shown at least that your solution contains all interesting solutions, it would have sufficed. As for your last sentence,

Comment: ...which is cleverly in hypothetical form, I laugh. Please recall you were the one piping on about Shafarevich, trying to divert our attention away from the main issue. In any case, I didn't say anything about whatever you think Shafarevich is -- indeed I stated that I didn't care what you thought of him. I wonder why you're being miffed now, since you were the one who actually made the irrelevant reference to his (purported) anti-Jewishness, so much so I was wondering what that had to do with anything. You're a very funny one, @Puquito.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU Sincerely yours. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the system as

\begin{align}
   (x+z) + (w+y) &= 30\\
   (x+z)(x-z)    &= (w+y)(w-y) \tag{1}
\end{align}

and make substitution $k = x + z,\, m = x - z,\, l = w + y,\, n = w - y$ to get

\begin{align}
   k + l &= 30\\
      km &= ln. \tag{2}
\end{align}

Obviously, any integral solution of $(1)$ gives us an integral solution of $(2)$. However, not every integral solution of $(2)$ will give an integral solution of $(1)$. Necessary and sufficient condition for an integral solution of $(2)$ to give an integral solution of $(1)$ is $k\equiv l \equiv m \equiv n \pmod 2$.

Thus, our strategy will be to describe all solutions of $(2)$, determine necessary and sufficient condition for $k\equiv l \equiv m \equiv n \pmod 2$ to hold, and therefore describe all solutions of $(1)$.

---

Let us solve $(2)$. Note that by substituting $l = 30 - k $ we get a homogeneous linear Diophantine equation in $m,\, n$ with parameter $k$:
$$ km - (30 - k)n = 0,$$
and thus, all of its solutions are given by
\begin{align}
   m &= \frac{30 - k}d t,\\
   n &= \frac kd t,\quad    t\in\mathbb Z,
\end{align}
where $d = \gcd(k,30-k) = \gcd(k,30).$

So, if $(k, l, m, n)$ is a solution of $(2)$, then it is of the form $(k, 30-k, \frac{30 - k}d t, \frac kd t),\ k,t\in\mathbb Z$. Obviously, any quadruple of that form is a solution of $(2)$.

---

We now have that any integral solution $(x, y, z, w)$ of $(1)$ is of the form

> \begin{align}
>    x &= \frac{kd + (30 - k)t}{2d}\\
>    y &= \frac{(30 - k)d - kt}{2d}\\
>    z &= \frac{kd - (30 - k)t}{2d}\\
>    w &= \frac{(30 - k)d + kt}{2d},   \quad k,t\in\mathbb Z. \tag{3}
> \end{align}

It remains to determine for which choices of $k, t\in\mathbb Z$ the above solution is integral. I claim that

> $(x, y, z, w)$ given by $(3)$ is in $\mathbb Z^4$ if and only if $k\equiv t \pmod 2$.

*Proof.* Let $(x, y, z, w)$ given by $(3)$ be in $\mathbb Z^4$. In particular, $k + \frac{30 - k}d t$ and $30 - k - \frac kd t$ are both even. Since $\frac kd$ and $\frac{30 - k}d$ are relatively prime, at least one of them is odd. WLOG, let it be $\frac kd$. Then,
$$30 - k - \frac kd t \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \implies k \equiv \frac kd t \pmod 2 \stackrel{\frac kd \equiv 1 \pmod 2}\implies k \equiv t \pmod 2.$$

Now, let $k \equiv t \pmod 2$. If both are even, then $k + \frac{30 - k}d t$, $30 - k - \frac kd t$, $k - \frac{30 - k}d t$ and $30 - k + \frac kd t$ are all even and thus $x, y, z, w \in \mathbb Z$. If they are both odd, then $\frac kd$ and $\frac{30 - k}d$ are also odd and the same conclusion holds. $\tag*{$\square$}$

> Therefore, all solutions of $(1)$ are given by $(3)$ with additional condition that $k \equiv t \pmod 2$.

---

**Example.** Let $k = 10$. Then $d = 10$ and
\begin{align}
   x &= 5 + t \\
   y &= 10 - \frac t2 \\
   z &= 5 - t \\
   w &= 10 + \frac t2,   \quad t \in 2\mathbb Z.
\end{align}
Letting $t = -2$ gives us solution $(3, 11, 7, 9)$.

---

Finally, let me remark that representation of a solution of $(1)$ by $(3)$ should be unique if I'm not making some silly mistake, i.e. different choices of pair $(k, t)$ will necessarily give us different quadruples $(x, y, z, w)$.

This is because different solutions $(k, l, m, n)$ of $(2)$ will give us different solutions $(x, y, z, w)$ of $(1)$ and different choices of $(k, t)$ will give us different solutions $(k, 30-k, \frac{30 - k}d t, \frac kd t)$ of $(2)$.

Comment: Using $d = \gcd(k, 30)$ in the formula might be unsatisfying. I don't know how to get rid of it, but one could always make a casework since $d\in\{1,2,3,5,6,10,15,30\}$.

Comment: Well done! This is definitely a better way to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that $w=\max \{x,y,z,w\}$ and $z=\min \{x,y,z,w\}$ (at the end we take all permutation). Write: $$(x-z)(x+z)= (w-y)(w+y)\implies $$

exists $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
x+z &=& ab\\ 
x-z &=& cd\\
w-y &=& ac\\
w+y&=&bd
\end{eqnarray}
so $b(a+d)= 30 \;\;\wedge \;\; d>a \implies b\leq 10$, so $b\in\{1,2,3,5,6,10\}$

- if $b=10$ then $a=1$ and $d=2$ so $x=...$
- if $b=6$ then $a=1$ and $d=4$ or $a=2$ and $d=3$...
- if $b=5$ then $a=1$ and $d=5$ or $a=2$ and $d=4$...
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Let $m,n$ be integers. Then we may write $$x=2mn,y=m^2-n^2,$$ so that the system becomes $$w^2+z^2=p,w+z=q,$$ where $p=m^2+n^2$ and $q=30-2mn-m^2+n^2.$

The $2×2$ system in $z,w$ may be easily solved, so that $z,w$ may also be explicitly written in terms of the integers $m,n.$ In particular, substitution gives the quadratic equation $$2z^2-2qz+q^2-p=0.$$ For the solutions $z$ to be integers, it is necessary that the discriminant $$2p-q^2$$ be a complete square.

A particular case of the analysis above with one of $z,w$ set to $0$ shows that there is no solution of the form $0,a,b,c.$